# Continuous Updating of Labels in Tkinter App

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

The following code works fine without any errors. But fundamentally there lies an issue. Once the alarm for first prayer is updated, it won't update even for the rest of the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, time

def check_current_prayer():
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    current_date = current_datetime.date()

    luhr_time_today = datetime.combine(current_date, time(hour=12, minute=0, second=0))
    asr_time_today = datetime.combine(current_date, time(hour=15, minute=0, second=0))

    if current_datetime >= asr_time_today:
        if str(current_datetime).split('.')[0] == str(luhr_time_today):
            current_prayer = "Asr Adhaan"
        next_prayer = "Maghrib Adhaan"
    elif current_datetime >= luhr_time_today:
        if str(current_datetime).split('.')[0] == str(asr_time_today):
            current_prayer = "Luhr Adhaan"
        next_prayer = "Asr Adhaan"
    elif current_datetime < luhr_time_today:
        current_prayer = "Luhr Adhaan"
        next_prayer_time = datetime.combine(current_date, luhr_time_today)
        next_prayer = "Luhr Adhaan"

    return current_prayer, next_prayer

def update_prayer_labels():
    current_prayer, next_prayer = check_current_prayer()
    current_prayer_label.config(text="Current Prayer: " + current_prayer)
    next_prayer_label.config(text="Next Prayer: " + next_prayer)
    root.after(1000, update_prayer_labels)

root = tk.Tk()

current_prayer_label = tk.Label(root, text="Current Prayer: ", font=("Arial", 14))
current_prayer_label.pack(pady=20)

next_prayer_label = tk.Label(root, text="Next Prayer: ", font=("Arial", 14))
next_prayer_label.pack(pady=10)

update_prayer_labels()

root.mainloop()
```

What I want is to keep looking for it even if the app is running for days. I tried changing the order thinking that it might be the issue lying with the order.

Comment: https://github.com/Kh4lidMD/AlAdhan/blob/main/aladhan/adhan.py  and https://gist.github.com/skeeph/3293106